# can the way a radically different idea is presented optimize the process of accommodation on the receiver's end?

Tags: learning-methods, idea, change

when conveying a new idea known to be radically differ from the 'receivers' existing schemas, thus, more likely to be successfully processed by accommodation vs assimilation, are there certain ways to present the idea that enhance the chance of thorough processing (via accomodation) at the other end?

adding this reference to cognitive learning terms accommodate vs assimilate. thanks to Jo Wehler for suggesting this clarification

https://www.simplypsychology.org/what-is-accommodation-and-assimilation.html

Comment: Please add your definition of the two terms "accommodation" vs "assimilation"; thanks.

Comment: https://www.simplypsychology.org/what-is-accommodation-and-assimilation.html

Comment: Due to the explanation from the link I recommend to place your question in its original form at https://psychology.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The most helpful precaution to take in such circumstances is to alert your audience to the fact that accommodation is needed, ideally pointing out exactly which concepts from their current mental schema they will have to jettison. A clear example of the need for accommodation is provided by Special Relativity. On Physics Stack Exchange there are endless questions from people who are struggling to understand SR precisely because they are trying to assimilate it into their existing mental model of space and time, with which it is fundamentally incompatible. From practical experience of attempting to answer their questions at a conceptual level, without resorting to mathematical expressions, it is as important to tell people what they need to forget as it is to tell them what they need to learn.